# AnyCase Searching Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ statement as follows:

```
myList = MyList.Where(x => 
    x.Name.Contains(SearchValue) ||
    x.Address.Contains(SearchValue)).ToList();
```

My Database can have upper or lower cases for the `Name` field like 'VSTS' or 'vsts'
I want my LINQ statement to execute with any case.

In the above LINQ statement if i provide with lower case values and the database is having upper case, the searching fails.. which i don't want.

Comment: Is this actually in LINQ to Objects, or a database-oriented provider?

Comment: its Linq to Objects, I have extracted the values from the database prior executing My linq statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring/444813#444813 .. Have you even tried to use google, before asking the question?

Comment: yup i did.. but possible my keywords didn't matched to get the Link..i needed it on urgent basis..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option would be using the ordinal case-insensitive comparison, however the `Contains` method does not support it, so your other option would be to use `string.IndexOf`.

It would be better to wrap this in an extension method, such as:

```
public static bool Contains(this string target, string value, StringComparison comparison)
{
    return target.IndexOf(value, comparison) >= 0;
}
```

So you could use:

```
myList.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(SearchValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                  x.Address.Contains(SearchValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
myList = MyList.Where(x => 
    x.Name.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(
        SearchValue.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) || 
    x.Address.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(
        SearchValue.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).
    ToList();
```

Comment: Normalizing should be made to Upper case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myList = MyList.Where(x => 
    x.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchValue.ToLower()) || 
    x.Address.ToLower().Contains(SearchValue.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Check if this works for Linq2Entity, could be the tolower fails :p

Comment: Normalizing should be made to Upper case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you may try the `ToLower()`:

```
myList = MyList.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchValue.ToLower()) 
    || x.Address.ToLower().Contains(SearchValue.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Comment: Normalizing should be made to Upper case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Contains() try this:

```
var svUP = SearchValue.ToUpper();
myList = MyList.Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper().Contains(svUP ) || x.Address.ToUpper().Contains(svUP )).ToList();
```

But if your fields contains full search value and only problem is casing then you should use Equals() with StingComparison instead:

```
myList = MyList.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(SearchValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || x.Address.Equals(SearchValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Comment: Best to use `ToUpperInvariant()` instead of `ToUpper()` =)